# url rewrite not working for a subfolder

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I'm trying to change some urls with url rewrite (apache), but nothing works and I just don't understand why. This is my .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mywebsite.it [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mywebsite.it [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://websiteip [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mywebsite.it/ [R,L]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteRule ^home$ /t01/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^chi-siamo$ /t01/chisiamo.php [L]
RewriteRule ^faq$ /t01/faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^login$ /t01/login_splash.php [L]
RewriteRule ^logout$ /t01/logout.php [L]

There is t01/ in front of the files because I'm trying to see if it works in a subfolder.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved everything by putting my files in the main directory and by cleaing my rules(no more t01/ ).